# Вопрос по поводу ударения в фамилии

Tags: орфоэпия

Здравствуйте! Как правильно поставить ударение во французской фамилии Леду?

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю, что за фамилия, но во французском ударение всегда на последний слог. Это касается и фамилий. Так что Лед**у**.

А, архитектор? Claude Nicolas Ledoux? Ну да, нет никаких причин переносить ударение.